# from 1.297503E+17 to 129750300000000000

Tags: php, timestamp, int

How can I get php to not use `1.297503E+17` on large int but `129750300000000000`

code:

```
$dag = 29;
$maand = 03;
$jaar = 2012;

$expdate = $dag . "-" . $maand . "-" . $jaar;
$unixstamp = strtotime($expdate);
echo $unixstamp."<br />";
$winstamp = ($unixstamp + 11644560000) * 10000000;
```

I'm trying to use the number for a Timestamp in ldap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I would do (tested on 32b platform)

```
>> number_format(1.297503E+17,0,'.','')
'129750300000000000'
```

just be aware, that what you get back is a string, an will be converted back to float if you try doing any arithemtics on it. If you need to do math on large integers look into [bc_math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) extension

Answer (score 0):

PHP internally uses big enough integers. Your problem here is the use of echo:

```
printf ("%d", $winstamp);
$winstamp++;
printf ("%d", $winstamp);
```

output:

```
129775320000000000
129775320000000001
```

Comment: I'm getting 
-587196416 if I do that

Comment: Actually internally PHP uses 32b or 64b long integers depending on if it was compiled for 32b or 64b platform. Any number longer than that gets converted to floating point representation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
echo rtrim(sprintf("%0.15f", $winstamp), "0.");
```

This uses sprintf to print a maximum of 15 decimal places, and then trims off any trailing 0 or . chars. (Of course, there's no guarantee that everything will be rounded nicely with trailing zeros as you might expect.)

If you just want a fixed size, then you can adjust the 15 and remove the rtrim.

Comment: I can't trim off anything seeing I need all the 0 given back from the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when PHP encounters a number that exceeds the upper limit of 2,147,483,647 for an integer, it automatically converts the number’s type from integer into a double.

Fortunately, we can format these numbers in scientific notation back to their standard integer form using the number_format() function. Here is how to do it:

```
$winstamp  = 1202400000; 
$formatted_stamp = number_format($winstamp , 0, '.', ''); 
echo $formatted_stamp; //outputs 1202400000 as expected
```